# Amcharts 5 CSS Element

Tags: css, amcharts, amcharts5

I'm using Amchart 5, I trying to customize the colors, labels and other stuffs using CSS. But Amchart 5 only shows the charts as Canvas not as individual element like amchart 4.

[amchart Canvas - Inspect Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogG1r.png)

If someone have solution please let me know, it'll be very helpful.

Thank you in advance.

I'm expecting a code to enables the css in the chart.

Comment: Please add what did you try (code) and read [mre] and [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As I'm planning to use this chart, I don't have the code, I only have screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use CSS this way with **amCharts 5** because, contrary to **amCharts 4**, it uses the **Canvas API** instead of **SVG**. There is an exception when you need [HTML content](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/common-elements/html-content/), though...

> Canvas API is generally way faster than SVG, however it paints outside DOM tree, which means you can't target individual chart elements via JavaScript or CSS.

[Migrating from amCharts 4 – amCharts 5 Documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/migrating-from-amcharts-4/)

To customize chart elements, you have to define settings in your JS code. A label, for instance, can be configured like this:

```js
am5.Label.new(root, {
  text: "Title",
  fill: am5.color("#ff0000"),
  fontSize: 25,
  fontWeight: "500",
  fontStyle: "italic",
  textAlign: "center",
  x: am5.percent(50),
  centerX: am5.percent(50),
  dy: -60
  // ...
});
```

You can find a complete list of settings there: [Label – amCharts 5 Documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/label/#Settings)

Here is a basic example:

```js
am5.ready(() => {
  
  let root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

  let chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
    paddingTop: 50
  }));
  
  // ========================= HERE =========================
  
  chart.children.unshift(am5.Label.new(root, {
    text: "Title",
    fill: am5.color("#ff0000"),
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: "500",
    fontStyle: "italic",
    textAlign: "center",
    x: am5.percent(50),
    centerX: am5.percent(50),
    dy: -50
  }));
  
  // ==================================================

  let xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
    categoryField: "category",
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {})
  }));

  let yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
  }));

  let series = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
    name: "Series",
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    categoryXField: "category",
    valueYField: "value"
  }));

  let data = [{
    category: "Category 1",
    value: 10
  }, {
    category: "Category 2",
    value: 20
  }, {
    category: "Category 3",
    value: 15
  }];

  xAxis.data.setAll(data);
  series.data.setAll(data);

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```